# Android Ionic App with JsPDF and html2canvas is generating blank pdf file on device

Tags: android, ionic-framework, jspdf, html2canvas

I'm new in ionic and when I tried to develop an Android based app I couldn't handle with this issue.

This app was built using ionic with jspdf.debug.js and html2canvas.js

When I test on device, the result is a blank pdf file, and I don't have any idea about how to solve this.

Could anyone give me a hand?

Bellow, the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <link href="css/styles.for.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!--Signature Components-->
    <link href="css/jquery.signaturepad.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.signaturepad.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.signaturepad.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/json2.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

    <script src="js/html2canvas.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.sigPad').signaturePad({ drawOnly: true });
        });
    </script>

    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!--ng-cordova-->
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter"> <!--onload="prepareCanvas()"--> <!--onload="onLoad()"-->
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">My App</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
        <!--<form>-->
            <div id="content" class="list">

                <div class="off-screen" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
                </div>
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum(Lorem Ipsum) - Lorem Ipsum" disabled="disabled">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum: Lorem Ipsum - Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum" disabled="disabled">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Lorem Ipsum: Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum" disabled="disabled">
                </label>                                        
                <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                    <span class="input-label">Equipe</span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Nome da Equipe">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                    <span class="input-label">Data</span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Data">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                    <span class="input-label">Area</span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Área">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                    <span class="input-label">Local</span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Local">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                    <span class="input-label">Atividade</span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Ativididade">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                    <span class="input-label">TipoNumDoc</span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Tipo e N° Documento">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                    <span class="input-label">Despachante</span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Despachante">
                </label>

                <div class="item item-divider">
                    Planejamento
                </div>

                <label class="item item-radio">
                    <input type="radio" name="group">
                    <div class="item-content">
                        Sim
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-content">
                        Não
                    </div>                        
                    <i class="radio-icon ion-checkmark"></i>
                </label>

                <div class="sigPad">
                    <!--<p class="drawItDesc current">Assine no quadro abaixo</p>-->
                    <ul class="sigNav">
                        <!--<li class="typeIt"><a href="#type-it" class="current">Type It</a></li>-->
                        <li class="drawIt"><a href="#draw-it" class="current">Assinar</a></li>
                        <li class="clearButton"><a href="#clear">Limpar</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="sig sigWrapper">
                        <div class="typed"></div>
                        <canvas class="pad" width="300" height="55"></canvas>
                        <input type="hidden" name="output" class="output">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <canvas id="canvas"> </canvas>

      </ion-content>
      <div class="bar bar-footer">
              <button class="button" onclick="prepareAPI()">Criar PDF Ionic</button>
              <div class="title">Title</div>
              <button class="button button-clear">Limpar</button>
            </div>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function prepareAPI() {
            alert("onDeviceReady");
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", createPdf(), false);
        }

        function createPdf() {
            var d_canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            var context = d_canvas.getContext('2d');
            var div = document.getElementById('content'); //.parentNode.style.overflow = 'visible';
            context.width = div.offsetWidth;
            context.height = div.offsetHeight;

            //FIRST GENERATE THE PDF DOCUMENT
            console.log("generating pdf...");
            alert("generating pdf...");

            html2canvas(content, {
                onrendered: function(d_canvas) {
                    document.body.appendChild(d_canvas);
                    //document.body.removeChild(clone);
                    console.log("Pegou html2canvas");
                    var imgData = d_canvas.toDataURL('image/png', context.width, context.height);
                    //var imgData = d_canvas.toDataURL('image/png', context.width, context.height);

                    doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');

                    console.log( imgData );
                    doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10, div.offsetWidth, div.offsetHeight);
                    //doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10, div.offsetWidth, div.offsetHeight);
                    pdfOutput = doc.output('blob');
                    saveFile(pdfOutput);
                }
            });

            //NEXT SAVE IT TO THE DEVICE'S LOCAL FILE SYSTEM
            var saveFile = function(pdfOutput) {
                console.log("file system...");
                window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {

                   console.log(fileSystem.name);
                   console.log(fileSystem.root.name);
                   console.log(fileSystem.root.fullPath);

                   fileSystem.root.getFile("test.pdf", {create: true}, function(entry) {
                      var fileEntry = entry;
                      console.log(entry);
                      alert("ENTRY " + entry);

                      entry.createWriter(function(writer) {
                         writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
                         console.log("write success");
                         alert("write success");
                      };

                      console.log("writing to file");
                      alert("writing to file");
                         writer.write( pdfOutput );
                         alert("PDFOUTPUT" + pdfOutput);
                      }, function(error) {
                         console.log(error);
                         alert(error);
                      });

                   }, function(error){
                      console.log(error);
                      alert(error);
                   });
                },
                function(event){
                 console.log( evt.target.error.code );
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
</html>
```